# How can I configure Maxima to index lists from 0 instead of 1?

Tags: maxima

If I create a list in Maxima:

`(%i1) a: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11];
(a) [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]`

Then if I index into that list and ask for element `4`:

`(%i2) a[4];
(%o2) 7`

This shows that Maxima uses 1-indexing rather than 0-indexing. I would prefer to use 0-indexing for lists rather than 1-indexing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the indexing for lists in Maxima; it always starts at 1.